# what is difference in char in C vs C# or JAVA

Tags: c#, java, c, char

I've stumbled on this while learning JAVA 
I've noticed that char takes 16 bit , while I remember that it takes 8 in C.
can someone explain why they are not resemble ?

Comment: A `char` is not necessarily 8-bits wide in C. The size of that type is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply read the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x9h8tsay.aspx)? EDIT: changed your tags to Java since you mentioned Java. If C# was right, change it back and include and explanation.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's 8 bits on all platforms where a byte has 8 bits though. So it's never used to represent multi-byte characters, which I think is the point here.

Comment: You stumbled on this while learning "JAVA" then why do your question read "C#" and the tag too?

Comment: @Abhineet you are right , I've never noticed it in C# until I saw it in JAVE :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# chars are Unicode, which is 16-bit, while C only uses ASCII, which is actually only 7 bits.

Comment: So, you are saying that there is no implementation of UNICODE chars in C???

Comment: To be precise, C# and Java use UTF16 for their `char` definition.

Comment: @Abhineet - C is about 30 years older than Unicode.  When C was written they were still trying to decide whether to use ASCII or USASCII or EBCDIC or FieldData or Baudot.

Comment: @HotLicks:: But I will still say that stating "C only uses ASCII" would be wrong.

Comment: If you need Unicode, there is library support for it, but it is not native: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html

Comment: @Abhineet - Actually, it's mostly correct.  The only place that C interfaces with the character set is in the compiler (obviously) and in string literals.  There have been versions of C written that supported EBCDIC instead of ASCII, but 99% of compilers are ASCII only.  C++ does, I believe, add some features to support Unicode escapes, but still doesn't really "know" what Unicode is.

Comment: @RobRibeiro thank you for your short answer